# Get Clipboard value from static variable

Tags: wpf, clipboard

So a sequel to my last post...

I have `PieChart` with `Legend` and i want to be able to right click on `Legend` title and copy the value.
So this is the `Legend Mouse Right click Event`:

```
private void pieLegend_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var hoveredItem = this.pieLegend.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsHovered);
    Clipboard.SetText(hoveredItem.Title);

}
```

As you can see i am copy the value the the `Clipboard` but i want to open simple `Copy` menu so i create `ContextMenu` and i have the `ContextMenu Click  Event`:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Not inside this `Click Event` i want to get the `Clipboard` but because `pieLegend_MouseRightButtonDown event` is fired before this `Click Event` i want to find a way to get this `Clipboard` value.
So i was thinking about create a `Static` variable that the first `Event` will set the `Clipboard` value and from the `Click Event` just get this value but my question is if this is the best way/appropriate way  to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's nothing wrong with doing both.

I think you are over thinking this, you really need to consider your **requirements**.

In this particular scenario, I would not suggest using the clipboard to *transfer* data from the two events. Why? Well, because the user can easily just copy something else onto their clipboard which may be completely unrelated to your application, therefore it could be erroneous.

So, I expect defining a private or static variable (This really depends on the scope, you don't need to define a static variable if you don't have to) is the correct way to go.

```
private string _HoveredItemTitle;

private void pieLegend_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var hoveredItem = this.pieLegend.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsHovered);
    Clipboard.SetText(hoveredItem.Title);

    _HoveredItemTitle = hoveredItem.Title;
}
```

And in your other method, it'd be a good idea to check if there is something in this variable, otherwise it may not be a good idea to go a head with the execution.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_HoveredItemTitle))
    {
        //TODO: Something useful
        return;
    }

    //TODO
}
```

I think the main idea I'm trying to get across here is that you should ensure that there is nothing (or as little as possible) that the user can do to cause errors in your application. In this scenario, copying the text to the clipboard is nice, but it's more of a *feature* than a *requirement*. The application should not have to rely on the clipboard, simply because there might be complete nonsense on the clipboard, instead of the data that you are actually expecting.

Comment: So instead of using Clipboard.SetText(_HoveredItemTitle) in case my string not null od empty what you suggest to do ?